# Apply two tasks with the same name

Tags: gradle

Let's say I have a file called `my-plugin.gradle`

```
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete '.gradle', 'build'
}
```

Then in another file `build.gradle`, I have

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'my-plugin'

clean {
  delete "${projectDir}/api-python/src"
}
```

I get `org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$DuplicateTaskException: Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.` error due to `my-plugin`.

Basically, these two `clean` tasks clean different things and for this specific `build.gradle`, I happen to need both. I have a lot of Gradle projects (I have a monorepo) and I would like to be able to compose tasks.

Is it possible in Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to apply the [base](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html) plugin from your own plugin. This registers the standard `delete` task (same as is used by the `java` plugin). You can then configure that in the same way as you did in the project build script:

```java
// my-plugin.gradle

apply plugin: 'base'

clean {
  delete "$rootDir/.gradle"
}
```

By the way, it is likely not a good idea to delete the Gradle project cache. Something is seriously broken in your build pipeline if this is needed. I am also not sure if bad things could happen if you delete the cache while Gradle is running.